# How do I find the return type of this curried function?

Tags: dart, currying

```
addition(int a) => (int b) => (int c) => a+b+c;
```

This is the function which returns `dynamic` for now

when I call `addition(1)(2)(3)` it prints 6 that's fine

I want to know the **exact** return type of this function

I am trying out the currying concept!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rahul say's, the current type, of the returned value, in your example would be `dynamic`. But if we want to apply a static know type it would be something like:

```dart
int Function(int) Function(int) addition(int a) =>
    (int b) => (int c) => a + b + c;

void main() {
  print(addition.runtimeType);
  // (int) => (int) => (int) => int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be dynamic. When nothing is specified, dynamic is the return type.

This statement could be broken as

```dart
addition(int a) {
  return (int b) {
    return (int c) {
      return a+b+c;
    };
  };
}
```

Here as none of the functions have any return type, they all have return type of dynamic

Comment: sorry sir! I updated my question.

Comment: To be clear, the anonymous functions have a return type of `dynamic` not because they don't have specified return types; the return types of anonymous functions are inferred.  The `addition` function has no explicit return type and is implicitly `dynamic`, and the return types of the anonymous functions are inferred to have `dynamic` return types from `addition`'s return type.